# How can i make fancy indexing in Lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd

I can see my directories and files in it by adding `dir-listing.activate = "enable"` to `/lighttpd.conf` but it only shows in alphabetical order. I can not click size or modification time title to sort as i want.

In nginx or apache we can easily sort by size or date by clicking titles which is called fancy indexing.

How can i do this in lighttpd?

PS: I tried `dir-generator.php`and `h5ai`. They are too slow.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd 1.4.41 now provides sortable columns in the default directory indexing.

If that is too slow for you, you can configure lighttpd to replace its short javascript with a link to any of the many available (larger) frameworks you can find in your favorite search engine and download to add to your document root.